# How to link/integrate code dependent from different 3rd Parties in Uniy3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependencies, conditional-compilation

We have a System in Unity3D which builds small Apps and is mainly based on interfaces.

For different solutions, I integrate a few different packages or Assets.  these dependencies conflict with each other so i can't integrate them all. The current state is, that each 3rd Party dependent code is in a different Git repo and gets cloned if needed.

My question is, if there is a better way to manage dependencies in Unity and is practicable for developing on the Main System and the different interface implementations and the same time?

One could use packages, but is there a way to automate building and integrating packages when developing on a package and same time testing it with the main system?

One could use a preprocessor directive in  each interface implementation to only compile when the 3rd party dependency is present, but that seems to be a pretty bad solution.

Whats the right way to do it?

Comment: Don't fully understand the bug picture.. but using conditional compilation sounds like a good idea actually .. you can use [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/conditional-compiling-check-if-a-namespace-plugin-is-available-using-if-endif-c.477121/#post-6279899) to check for the existence of a type

Comment: The linked [ConditionaCompilationUtility](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ConditionalCompilationUtility) is a good choice to derive defines from existing classes.
That'll be helpful if my now chosen approach with packages did not meet my needs.
The question was more general. What is best practice to manage many and changing dependencies in Unity when developing on a project and on these dependencies at the same time?

Comment: Use a different git repo but bind it into the project repository as a git submodule and in Unity reference it as a  local package  => you are up to date, can reference different branches and versions via the git submodule.. and by binding it as a local package you can fully modify the package while using it in the project

Comment: @derHugo thanks, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it